# Как сделать прозрачный фон на весь экран, с прозрачным ActionBarom?

Tags: android

[image: Картинка]

Как реализовать такое с AppBarom?
Я как понимаю без Toolbarа тут не обойдись?

Answer (score 0):

если ActionBar:
настройте прозрачный ActionBar

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

сделайте изображение для фона, фоном вашего Window

```
 getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable);
//или setBackgroundDrawableResource(id);
```

если Toolbar:

```
getSupportActionBAr().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable);
//или setBackgroundDrawableResource(id);
```

добавте в xml разметку вашего layout с Toolbar,перед Toolbar View с height 25 и width match_parent

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```